# I have installed nagios core but unable to access it through web interface

Tags: linux, nagios

Throws an error 404 file or dir not found and I am installing it first time
I don't have any clue.Can you help finding the cause ?
I am trying to access nagios web-interface from a remote machine.I have verified nagios,httpd daemon is running properly on the server (rhel 7.4).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unjSl.png)ck.imgur.com/rRK46.png

Comment: What address are you trying to open in your browser? Are the browser and Nagios Core on the same machine? Are you sure the core is running? How exactly can you tell it's running? Please do not answer in comments, [edit] the question instead.

Comment: Look at the log file produced by the webserver (both access and error log if applicable) should give you some hints.

Comment: Also, what web server are you running, what do the config files show? If Apache, what files are in /etc/httpd/sites-enabled and /etc/init.d/mifs-enabled